# Issue with Map using Folium

Tags: python, folium

trying to display a map using Folium and I am getting the type error message below. this is what i have in my code cells.

```
import folium 
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

    
lat = df.dropna()['BEGIN_LAT']
#lat.head()
lon = df.dropna()['BEGIN_LON']
locations = list(zip(lat, lon))
lon_lat = (37.09024, -95.712891)

map = folium.map(location = lon_lat, zoom_start = 7, tiles ="OpenStreetMap")
map=folium_hmap
heat_map = HeatMap(locations)
heat_map.add_to(map)
map
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-fa79a3781f76> in <module>
----> 1 map = folium.map(location = lon_lat, zoom_start = 7, tiles ="OpenStreetMap")
      2 map=folium_hmap
      3 heat_map = HeatMap(locations)
      4 heat_map.add_to(map)
      5 display(map)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo : it is `folium.Map()` with a capital M. You also need to remove the line `map=folium_hmap`